# How to replace HP SFF power supply of 240W by a more powerful power supply?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power

I have an [HP Compaq Elite 8300 PC SFF](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03343457#N10021), with this power supply: [613762-001](http://partsurfer.hp.com/ShowPhoto.aspx?partnumber=613762-001). The documentation says that the current power supply is (only) 240W.

I'd like to increase performance by installing a [750 TI graphics card](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-750-ti/specifications), which needs 300-400W power.

Can I replace the existing power supply by a new one? If so, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: You first have to determine if HP like Dell uses power supplies with non-standard connectors.  Once you determine that, you purchase a power supply with the same connector, but also supplies higher wattage.  Be sure you identify power supplies that will fit in the case, you might have to stick with power supplies that came with the Compaq Elite, in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I installed the 750TI card, and the system works like a charm